# What kind of matrix norm is this?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been told that $|AB|\leq |A||B|$ where the norm of a matrix is defined as the sum of absolute values of each entry.

I am curious as to what this type of norm is called. I was browsing wikipedia and this site for an explanation of the proof, but the norms I am finding are all much different than this simple norm. Perhaps I could narrow down my search if I knew what this norm was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering matrices as vectors this is called the [Taxicab Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm).